# "Interview-Questions" Tag

Tags: discussion, tags

We had at least one interview question on the site already. This is not a proposal to ban them or anything like that, but I think a tag like [interview-question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interview-question) would be beneficial for everyone:

- The Question might get more attention, since it's always good to see what questions might be asked in interviews
- Similar to the [homework](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework)-Tag, it is a "full disclosure" where the question comes from
- And someone who will go to a job interview can just read through some of the tagged questions to get an idea what to expect.

Opinions?

Comment: If I were new to the site, I would expect this to reflect questions *about interview questions* - not questions that happened to have been asked at interviews.

Comment: Note that the homework tag has been reason for [controversy](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/17/homework-tag-discussion), too.

Answer (score 3):

Why the hell would we want to tag a question differently because it was once given in an interview? [interview-question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interview-question) says absolutely nothing about what the question is about. It is useless. Kill it if it ever arises.

Comment: I disagree for the reasons stated above. It should never be used without other tags to provide context, but it gives additional information about the question and it's context.

Comment: @malexmave No, [tag:interview-question] does not give any information about the question. Anyone can ask any question in an interview. Also, a tag that can't be used as the sole tag is a bad sign; please read [The Death of Meta Tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

Comment: The gist of "[The Death of Meta Tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)" is that tagging should be used to tell you *what* the question is about, not *why* it was asked. This question is not about "interview questions" so it should **not** have that tag.